# How can I go back to the previous page after updating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I go back to the previous page (where the items in question were listed) from the edit view (edit.html.erb) after clicking on the update button? I have tried:

```rb
redirect_to request.referer #stays on the same page(edit.html.erb) 
redirect_to session.delete(:return_to) #outputs "Cannot redirect to nil!"
redirect_to :back #stays on same page
redirect_back fallback_location: posts_path #stays on same page
redirect_to(request.env['HTTP_REFERER']) #stays on same page
```

In the database, the comment is updated.

While I can use posts_path(@comment), I want to also edit comment from another url. Hence the need for a redirect to the previous page.

Comment: Don't forget. When you are on the `edit` page and you submit the form, you referrer on the `update` action is `edit` page. You cannot use `redirect_back` or anything similar. You have to tell your edit form, where you user came from, and send this information to `update` action and then redirect back according to this parameter or something similar.

Comment: @edariedl Thank you for your answer. So I can't have one redirect that sends users to their previous url no matter which url that is (because the comment form is on multiple places)?

Comment: You can, but there is no feature like this directly in rails, you would have to develop it by yourself or try to find some gem that could help you with it.

Comment: @edariedl Great, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `request.referer` to directly back the the previous of edit page. Cause on the `update` method, the `request.referer` will be always the `edit` path.

You can, do a trick like, parse the `request.referer` of `edit` action (might be the `index` one, for ex. as params to `update` action, and redirect to the path on updating the resource )

```
# edit form view
<%= hidden_field_tag :previous_request, request.referer %>

# update action
def update
  ...
  redirect_to params[:previous_request]
end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!